# How do I specify the path to XYZ when I use configure --with-XYZ=yes

Tags: configure, automake

I am trying to compile c-sources with the `configure`, `make`, `make install` trilogy.

Since I want to compile the sources so that they use another library (XYZ) that is not used by default, I can specify that with a

```
./configure --with-XYZ=yes
```

However, for the moment, XYZ is not installed in a default location, so I guess I can specify the path to the location of XYZ with that same configure script. If my guess is right, I'd appreciate if someone could point me towards the right direction of how to do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Specify the library path on the command line like this:

```
./configure --with-XYZ=yes LDFLAGS=-L/path/to/xyz
```

Comment: +1 LDFLAGS=... has hinted me to the right direction. For completness' sake, I also had to specify `CPATH=...`.

Answer (score 2):

The most general way is to specify the `LDFLAGS` (for `-L`) and `CPPFLAGS` (for `-I`) variables, like ptomato described.

In many cases, there are other ways that are specific to the option and the package that provides it.  Sometimes it might be `--with-XYZ=PATH`, sometimes it could be `--with-XYZ-path=PATH`, sometimes `pkg-config` is involved.  You need to read the particular installation documentation, or more often than not do some detective work.

Comment: Using --with-XYZ=PATH, etc. to specify paths is specifically prohibited by the GNU programming conventions.  Use LDFLAGS and CPPFLAGS instead.

Comment: @Dana: You're right, but that hasn't stopped many people from doing it anyway. :)  So when you write software, don't do it that way.  But when you want to build someone else's software, expect that it could work that way.